# Creation of Paypal encrypted button returns the error 11945 invalid country and locale combination

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-buttons

I am implementing the creation of encrypted Paypal buttons using their [Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/). Despite all my efforts I am facing the error [`11945 The button country and language code combination specified is invalid.`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/#bmcreatebutton-errors).

First I tried to implement the creation of my own button but while tracing this error, I ended up with [their tutorial using `curl`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/gs_PayPalPaymentsStandard/#try-it), which fails for me too with the same error. (Note: I had to change the credentials to mine).

To be specific, this code from their tutorial fails with the error 11945:

```
curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp \
  -s \
  --insecure \
  -d USER=<my-user-name> \
  -d PWD=<my-password> \
  -d SIGNATURE=<my-signature> \
  -d VERSION=51.0 \
  -d METHOD=BMCreateButton \
  -d BUTTONCODE=ENCRYPTED \
  -d BUTTONTYPE=CART \
  -d BUTTONSUBTYPE=PRODUCTS \
  -d BUTTONCOUNTRY=US \
  -d L_BUTTONVAR1=item_name%3Dshoehorn \
  -d L_BUTTONVAR2=amount%3D1464.46 \
  -d L_BUTTONVAR3=tax=%3D21 \
  -d L_BUTTONVAR4=item_number%3D123456
```

I tried to figure out why is that but I haven't found any relevant sources.

Can anyone explain this issue? The country code is set to `US`, which should be fine.

All help will be appreciated.

Note: I am using the sandbox right now.

Note: Defining locale through `lc` attribute does not help. I tried `en` as well as `en_US` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a [discussion](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-HTML-Buttons/Button-creation-through-Button-Manager-API-ends-with-error-11945/td-p/1249793/highlight/false) with the Paypal support, there is the conclusion.

**Short version:** It's a bug.

**Long version (by moderator MTS_Ciaran):**

> Thanks, so this looks like a bug on the sandbox from what I can see.
>   The issue is that the account is CZ and for some reason we're not
>   allowing the button creation because of that. It doesnt look to be the
>   same on the live environment so I would suggest using a US account for
>   testing and once live the CZ account shouldn't be an issue.
>
> I'll
>   work internally to get the sandbox corrected for this.